There's a weird sound that plays every few minutes (24.04.1)
It sounds like a bell or a chime, almost exactly like /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga.
I've tried logging all the sounds using watch -n0.5 'pacmd list-sink-inputs | tee -a sound-inputs.log' and got nothing. After listening to all the wav and ogg files on my system I tried deleting complete.oga and the sound still plays. It's driving me insane and I don't know what to do.
Something seems fishy about having a whole bunch of entries for the Clocks app under Settings -> Sound -> Volume Levels.
EDIT: I'm pretty sure it's the clocks app making that sound, because the sound is the same as the one that plays whenever a timer is done. But this happens even when I don't have any timers going off or anything.

I assume that you have tried re-booting and that the behaviour persists.  Normally for any sound that won't go away I solve it by typing into my terminal:
killall pulseaudio

And it stops.
If you think that a clock app is causing the problem, remove it and try a different one:  sudo snap install gnome-clocks
